# Ruby organization with multiple source files

Tags: ruby, yaml, organization

I am trying to figure out the best way to organize a bunch of Ruby scripts to make it easier on the next person. One key thing is that there are multiple constant variables that need to be used across all scripts. Where should these be stored? Do I keep a separate file for these constants? Should I use YAML? I've never had to create a project with multiple Ruby source files interacting with each other, so I'm not sure as to what the best method of approach is here.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use a `config.yaml` file for all my constants. This makes it easy to set and change variables that are going to be used across different files. Then all you need to do is read in the file and set the variables. You can keep this file anywhere really, so long as anyone using the file has read permissions. All you have to do then is set the file path.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where would you recommend I store common functions? That is, functions that I will be using in multiple source files.

Comment: Well, that depends. Typically if you have methods you want to share, you would make one class a sub-class of another.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do a config.yml or settings.yml, but I also allow the variables defined in config.yml to be overloadable by ENV variables (might be overkill in your situation).

It's might also be a good idea to set some defaults in your config loading/setting code.

As far as common functions/methods go... common.rb is a pretty good name or maybe shared.rb.